# I can't have two classes pointing at each other

Tags: c++, class, pointers, syntax, compiler-errors

This code

```
class x {
    y* ptrY;
};
class y {
    x* ptrX;
};
int main() {

}
```

Gives me these unhelpful errors[image: rather cryptic errors]

Am I doing something that is not allowed or there is a way around this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `x` is defined, `y` is not known yet, so `x` can't be compiled properly. One way around this is to use a forward declaration - essentially, you'd be declaring that "`y` is a class, and I'll define it later":

```cpp
class y; // Forward declaration of y

class x {
    y* ptrY;
};
class y {
    x* ptrX;
};
int main() {
}
```

Comment: Actually "When `x` is defined ..."   is more accurate than "When `x` is declared ...".       Your sample can be preceded by a declaration of `x`  (i.e.  what you are describing as a "forward declaration).       The problem is that `y` must be declared before `x` is defined, AND `x` must be declared before `y` is defined.

Comment: @Peter That's better wording, thanks. Edited.